Numerical integration of ODEs: Why does higher accuracy and precision not lead to convergence?

I'm trying to integrate numerically a non-linear ODE that, on paper, is simple (just the damped, forced pendulum), but that, as well known, its dynamics displays a chaotic behavior and is very sensitive to initial conditions. On longer time spans, it becomes difficult to obtain a convergent answer. This is expected, due to the nature of the dynamical system. But my problem is that increasing the numerical accuracy and precision, even by several orders of magnitude, leads only to a slightly better convergence. And I'm wondering why?
Some details follow.
This is the second order ODE of the damped and forced pendulum:
\begin{equation}
    \ddot{\theta} + 2\beta \dot{\theta} + \omega_{0}^2 \sin \theta = \gamma \omega{_0}^2 \cos{\omega t},
\end{equation}
with $\theta$ the angular excursion, the term on the rhs is the harmonic forcing, and where $\omega=2\pi$, $\omega_0=\frac{3}{2}\,\omega=3\pi$, $\beta=\frac{\omega_0}{4}=\frac{3\pi}{4}$, $\gamma=1.16$.
This can be reduced to a first-order ODE by the substitution ($y_{1}=\theta $):
$$y'_{1}=y_2.$$
Then it becomes:
\begin{equation}
    y'_{2} + 2\beta y_{2} + \omega{_0}^2 \sin y_{1} = \gamma \omega{_0}^2 \cos{\omega t},
\end{equation}
with initial conditions $y_{1}(t_0)=\theta(t_0)$ and $y_{2}(t_0)=y'_{1}(t_0)=\dot{\theta}(t_0)$.
I use a Bulirsch-Stoer integrator in Matlab which is supposedly the most adequate for high precision numerical integrations (except for functions with singularities, which isn't the case here.) Indeed, it performs better than a RK, but not that much as expected. The picture shows the numerical solutions for different tolerances (the accuracy of the solution at the grid-points.) Until about $27$ seconds (dynamical time of the pendulum), all solutions are the same, but then begin to diverge for the different tolerances. Of course, this is expected. For different accuracies, the solutions must turn out differently beyond a certain time interval. What was not expected that no matter what tolerance is applied, they all begin to diverge at about the same time. I expected that applying lower tolerances (e.g., here four tolerances, from $10^-20$ to $10^-23$) one could obtain accurate solutions going beyond the $27$ second limit. Not so. One factor is that double precision isn't sufficient. So I implemented a multiprecision tool that allows to calculate with arbitrary numbers of digits. I went so far in using 300 digits!! This allows to go further by about ten seconds, but then that's it. No matter how much accuracy and precision one applies, convergence doesn't work beyond a $40$ seconds barrier, either. I wondered whether the integrator works and does its job. Solving ODEs with known analytic solutions, I could check that it does indeed do the right thing. So, I think that there is something fundamentally flawed in my procedure (or my thinking.) My question is: Why does one not observe converge the solutions from a certain level of accuracy and precision onwards? What could be the underlying cause for such a behavior, or what is my mistake?

You might want to try using better integrators such as Vern7/Vern9. Bulirsch-Stoer is only 2nd order which means it will be pretty inefficient as your tolerance gets stricter.

I would wager that, if an IEEE double is diverging at 27 seconds and AFP at 300 dp is diverging at 40 seconds for the various tolerances, then there's probably something going on with the number of digits and the solution.

Is it in Julia's SciML? Does it work with arbitrary precision as well?

it is and it does (it also supports about 300 other integrators with various properties)

Perhaps you could spell out explicitly the ode’s that you are numerically solving. You may just be hitting an unstable region of the attractor for example. It could also be a numerical artifact as Kyle Kanos suggested. With just what you are telling us, it is hard to settle the problem.

@naturallyInconsistent if you are referring to the butterfly effect in Lorenz 69, then it should not apply here. I think that the OP is simply considering ode’s with a finite number of degrees of freedom. Cauchy-Lipschitz guarantees continuity with initial conditions etc. You need infinite degrees of freedom to have many different time scales as suggested in the original article.

Wait long enough and chaos ensues

@LPZ Above I added the equation. However, I doubt it could furnish more insights, unless one takes the time to integrate it numerically and see if one gets the same.

@naturallyInconsistent I have never seen Sabine being shocked.

Crossposted from https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/828249/2451

This is the nature of chaos. the number of digits of precision you need to obtain convergence to time t is often exponential in t.
That said, using better integrators, it is possible to do better.
using OrdinaryDiffEq, Plots
function pend(dy, y, p, t)
    (;gamma, w, w0, B) = p
    dy[1] = y[2]
    dy[2] = gamma*w0^2*cospi(w*t) - w0^2*sin(y[1]) - 2*B*y[2]
end
# guessing at initial conditions because you didn't give them in the post
prob = ODEProblem(pend, BigFloat[0, 0], (big"0.0",50), (gamma=1.16, B=3*big(pi)/4, w0=3*big(pi), w=2))
sol2 = solve(prob, Vern7(), abstol=1e-20, reltol=1e-20);
sol2 = solve(prob, Vern7(), abstol=1e-22, reltol=1e-22);
plot(sol1, idxs=2) # blue
plot!(sol2, idxs=2) # orange



Sure. But I started with 36 significant decimal digits (quad precision), then 100, now 300, and still nothing. Will try 1000, 10000, 10000000000000000000000000000000000....... But I find it strange that it doesn't go beyond 40 seconds.

going from 25 to 35 seconds is hard. Every extra 10 seconds will require tightening down the precision and tolerances more and more.

This is one of the primary benefits of using Julia's ODE environment, especially compared to MATLAB. The ability to swap to a non-standard integrator without having to scour the file exchange is great for testing stuff like this

Oh... this looks interesting. I definitely will have to learn Julia. My initial conditions where y(0)=0 and y'(0)=0 (it is a forced pendulum, it can start from rest.) I guess it should be w=2*big(pi) (?)

@Mark I switched the definition of w to be in rotations rather than radians  (since cospi is likely going to be slightly better than cos numerically).

@Oscar I installed Julia and get the same. Great! :)
I guess BigFloat[0, 0] are the initial conditions. Right? The problem is that in Matlab I get a very different graph (see picture above). I expected both graphs to coincide at least for an initial time span (say from 0-25 seconds.)
I think the first Sol2 should be Sol1.

correct on the initial conditions. I'm not sure why the results aren't matching Matlab. they should be (assuming I translated correctly and the Matlab solver is correct)

I suspect you are plotting the derivative, not the solution. For few seconds it is like my y'(t). I think the Bulirsch-Stoer integrator does the right thing because it coincides with Matlab's RK until 25 seconds. Then B-S and RK diverge from each other. Moreover, I checked whether B-S fits ODEs which analytic solution is known, and it does so.

As Oscar states, one of the definitions of chaos is that errors in a trajectory are magnified exponentially in time. However, note that although you lose accuracy on the trajectory, the strange attractor itself is stable so you will still simulate a trajectory on the attractor (or morely likely, some approximation of the attractor). This can be used to compute properties of the attractor such as time-averages, delay embeddings, Lyapunov exponents, etc. This is done even on mission critical simulations such as turbulent fluid simulations for aeronautics.

At some point, assuming your y scale is in radians, two differing solutions get arbitrarily close to an unstable inverted configuration.  The solutions diverge noticeably when one solution tips back to rotate before going over center, while the other one makes it over.  But even before that, the two solutions are slowly diverging in a less obvious way.
The time horizon for solution divergence in a chaotic system is on the order of
$\frac{1}{\lambda} ln\frac{a}{|\delta_0|}$  where
$a$ is a measure of error tolerance, $\lambda$ is a Lyapunov exponent that governs the growth of the error, and $\delta_0$ is a measure of the amplitude of the intial error.
So, as others have noted, it's an unfortunate mathematical fact that vastly improving integration accuracy does not result in a very large gain in "accurate" solution time.  Because its all under the natural log.
Source for horizon equation and further discussion: "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos" by Steve Strogatz.

That's interesting. However, I don't get it how this formula works. What is meant by the "initial error"? I guess it is the numerical precision (because the initial conditions are set to exact integers, and the error is determined only by the number of digits). If one sets the error tolerance equal to the error amplitude of the initial condition, the time horizon becomes zero. Not clear to me... In which chapter of Strogatz's book is mentioned this?

I found this one: https://www.tud.ttu.ee/web/dmitri.kartofelev/YFX1560/LectureNotes_9.pdf
It clarifies my above doubts. Thanks so far.

The link you sent reads very similar to the Strogatz text.  The error tolerance $a$ has to be higher than numerical precision because it's the error ceiling where you decide that the discrepancy is too large and no longer acceptable.  For example, if your integrator accuracy is 1e-8, you might consider discrepancies of 1e-3 to be too large.  In general yes it simplifies down to the order of $1/\lambda$.  But that goes back to the point that improving integrator tolerance doesn't do much.  The discussion is in CH9 of my (old) edition "Chaos On A Strange Attractor."

"If one sets the error tolerance equal to the error amplitude of the initial condition, the time horizon becomes zero."   What this means is that you have equated your definition of "inaccurate" ($a$) with the integrator tolerance.  Thus all solutions are "inaccurate" right from the beginning.
