Why do different ODE solvers give very different solutions to this problem?
I want to simulate the system defined by the following ordinary differential equations with periodic boundary conditions with $N$ lattice sites
\begin{equation}
i\frac{d}{dt}\phi_n = (1 + |\phi_n|^2)\sum\limits_{m=1}^{N-1}\frac{\phi_{n+m} + \phi_{n-m}}{m^{1+\alpha}},\; \alpha >0,
\end{equation}
where $\phi_n(t)\in\mathbb{C}$. This Hamiltonian system has two conserved quantities defined under a weighted Poisson bracket defined by
\begin{equation}
\{f,g\}:=i\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}\left [ (\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_n^{\ast}}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi_n} - \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_n}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi_n^{\ast}})(1+|\phi_n|^2)\right ]
\end{equation}

Hamiltonian $H = -\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1}\left [ \phi_{n-1}\phi_n^{\ast} - \phi_{n-1}^{\ast}\phi_n\right ]$,
$P = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{N-1}\ln(1+|\phi_n|^2)$

To apply periodic boundary conditions, consider the use of modular arithmetic and the Riemann and Hurwitz zeta functions respectively defined as  $\zeta(s) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^s}$ and $\zeta(s,a) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+a)^s}$.
Let $n \in -N, \cdots, N-1$ and since $m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}$, then $m = (2N)q + r$ where $q \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and $r = 0,1,\cdots, 2N-1$. Additionally, since $m$ is a positive integer, then $q$ and $r$ cannot be $0$ simultaneously.
\begin{align}\sum\limits_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^{+}}\frac{\phi_{n+m} + \phi_{n-m}}{m^{1+\alpha}} &= \sum\limits_{\substack{r = 0 \\ (r,q) \neq (0,0)}}^{2N-1} \sum\limits_{q\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0}}\frac{\phi_{n + (2N)q + r} + \phi_{n - (2N)q -r}}{((2N)q + r)^{1+\alpha}}\end{align}
\begin{align}
&= \frac{2\phi_{n}}{(2N)^{1+\alpha}}\sum_{q\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\frac{1}{q^{1+\alpha}} + \frac{1}{(2N)^{1+\alpha}}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{2N-1} \Big ( \phi_{n+r} + \phi_{n-r}\Big) \sum\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}\frac{1}{(q + \frac{r}{2N})^{1+\alpha}}\\
&= \frac{2\phi_{n}}{(2N)^{1+\alpha}} \zeta(1+\alpha) + \frac{1}{(2N)^{1+\alpha}}\sum\limits_{r = 1}^{2N-1} \Big ( \phi_{n+r} + \phi_{n-r}\Big) \zeta(1+\alpha, \frac{r}{2N})
\end{align}
I want to understand why I get similar but different figures when I evolve the system and plot the modulus-squared of the solution data $|\phi_n|^2$. The two ode solvers that I test are ode45 and ode113. Further, how do I know which one is the correct one? In the below Matlab code, [tt,u] = ode113(RHS, [0,timeSpan],initial_condition,opts); % Solve problem  is used, but I swap ode113 with ode45 for that corresponding experiment. No other change is made. The output of the two experiments is: (LEFT is ode113, RIGHT is ode45)

s = settings; s.matlab.appearance.figure.GraphicsTheme.TemporaryValue = "light";
close all
clear all
tic

L = 1024; % Grid size
dx=1; % Unit grid spacing
x=[-L/2:dx:L/2-dx]'; % Grid

[row col] = size(x);
%% Parameters
alpha = 1; % Fixed value of alpha used in calculating A

kappa = 0.0;
timeSpan = 1000;


initial_condition = 0.3*exp(1i*kappa*x);
Average_initial = mean(initial_condition);
sprintf("Average square amplitude of the phonons: %0.5f ", Average_initial)


filename_intensity_evolution   = sprintf("45planewave_time_%0.5f_k_%0.5f_alpha_%0.5f__amplitudeAvg_%0.5f.png",timeSpan,kappa,alpha,Average_initial);
filename_intensity_evolutionBW = sprintf("45planewaveBW_time_%0.5f_k_%0.5f_alpha_%0.5f__amplitudeAvg_%0.5f.png",timeSpan,kappa,alpha,Average_initial);
filename_intensity_start       = sprintf("45START_planewave_time_%0.5f_k_%0.5f_alpha_%0.5f__amplitudeAvg_%0.5f.png",timeSpan,kappa,alpha,Average_initial);
filename_intensity_end         = sprintf("45END_planewave_time_%0.5f_k_%0.5f_alpha_%0.5f__amplitudeAvg_%0.5f.png",timeSpan,kappa,alpha,Average_initial);

%% Define the problem: d/dt u_n = -i * ( 1 + |u_n|^2 ) * L_alpha u_n) 

% Periodic boundary condition coefficient matrix
LRI_MATRIX = AL_PERIODIC(L/2,alpha); 

% ODE system solver
RHS = @(t,u) -1i*( LRI_MATRIX*u + abs(u).^2 .* (LRI_MATRIX * u) );
opts = odeset('Reltol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-11,'Stats','on');

[tt,u] = ode113(RHS, [0,timeSpan],initial_condition,opts); % Solve problem

%% Evolution plotting

% Black & White intensity plot
figure
imagesc(tt,x,abs(u)'.^2 > 0.3); 

colormap(flipud(gray));
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
shading interp;
xlabel("TIME");
ylabel("Grid"), 

exportgraphics(gcf,filename_intensity_evolutionBW);


function omega_k = dispersion_relation(kappa)
    omega_k = kappa^2 / 2 - pi * kappa + pi^2 / 3;
end
function M = AL_PERIODIC(N,a)
tic

I_N = -N:1:N-1;
r_INDEX = 1:1:2*N-1;

%% Initialize the coefficient matrix for the LRI operator

%% Populate the diagonal 
M_DIAG = 2*zeta(1+a)*(1 / (2*N)^(1+a) ) * eye(2*N);

temp = zeros(1,2*N);

n = 1;
for r = 1:numel(r_INDEX)
    % Go through the r indexed sum.
    
    % Compute the indices n+r, n-r.
    congruence_sum = mod(I_N(n) + r_INDEX(r), 2*N);
    congruence_difference = mod(I_N(n) - r_INDEX(r), 2*N);
    
    % Compute the coefficient values
    znr =  (hurwitzZeta(1+a, r/(2*N)));
       
    znr = 1/(2*N)^(1+a) * znr;
    
    % Increment M_DENSE_firstRow on the corresponding columns
    temp(congruence_sum        + 1) = temp(congruence_sum        + 1) + znr;
    temp(congruence_difference + 1) = temp(congruence_difference + 1) + znr;
end
% Do the same order flipping that the original did
M_DENSE = toeplitz([temp(N+1:end),temp(1:N)]);

M = M_DENSE + M_DIAG;
sprintf("Nonlocal operator constructed in: %0.5f",toc)
end


Do the systems look similar at very short times? It might be that this nonlinear system is chaotic. A way to test this would be to slightly perturb the initial condition and run it with the same ODE solver and see if you get very different trajectories after a long time

@whpowell96 At very short times, yes they look very similar.

@whpowell96 As a follow up to your question, I took a look at the odestats for each solver attempt. The ode113 solver stats are 447378 successful steps 313 failed attempts 895070 function evaluations and the ode45 solver stats are ``1.7326e+06 successful steps
0 failed attempts
1.03956e+07 function evaluations 
The ode45 solver took many more steps than the ode113 attempt. Does a "long time" simulation correspond to total number of steps or the size of the final time (here $t_f = 1000$)?

113 typically takes fewer steps than 45s for stiff problems or problems with lower tolerances. I would try comparing multiple solvers at low tolerances and comparing the same solver with slightly perturbed initial conditions to determine if nearby trajectories are diverging from each other.

In general, if you apply two numerical methods to the same problem and get different answers, there are four possible reasons:

One or both of the implementations has a bug.  This is especially likely if the code hasn't been tested before.  In your case, these codes have been tested extensively so this is the least likely possibility.

One or both of the methods is not consistent or not stable.  For the methods involved here there are proofs of consistency and stability, so you can discard this possibility.

You haven't set the tolerance tight enough (or your mesh size is too large), so that the numerical errors are large.  Since different methods will produce different numerical errors, this will lead to different solutions.  Here you've set the tolerances much smaller than the visible errors, so this doesn't seem to be the issue.

The mathematical problem you are solving is ill-conditioned.  This means that the solution is very sensitive to perturbations.  This has nothing to do with the numerical methods, but only with the problem itself.   Since all numerical methods produce perturbations (numerical errors), then this will inevitably lead to differing numerical solutions.


Of course, issues #3 and #4 are intertwined, and you can to some extent solve #4 by continuing to reduce the size of the numerical errors.  How to do that depends on the nature of the errors: for rounding errors, use higher-precision arithmetic; for truncation errors, use a finer mesh.
However, in some cases it's simply not feasible to compute accurate solutions.  Most notably, if the system has solutions that diverge exponentially over time, then the accuracy of long-time solutions will be quite limited no matter what you do.  This is the case for chaotic systems and for some other ill-posed problems.
Edit to address the comment below: For Hamiltonian systems, using a symplectic or energy-preserving integrator can drastically improve the accuracy of very long-time simulations of the system, since it can make the error grow linearly (rather than the generic quadratic growth) in time.  This has been shown in the work of Angel Duran and co-authors.  This won't really help with accuracy for chaotic systems, though it can give solutions that are more statistically similar to the exact solution.

Would using a symplectic method make a difference?

Symplectic integrators might yield marginally better accuracy (and definitely better conservation), but if the problem is genuinely sensitive to initial conditions then that won't matter much. The only options are to crank up the order/down the tolerances. Unfortunately, MATLAB does not have too many options for changing the integrator so you may have to just lower the tolerances a lot and see which performs better

Comparing both schemes with very tight tolerances is the way to go. Regarding the chaotic or high sensitivity character of the equation, the explanation given in a previous question can also be helpful: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/44542/numerical-integration-of-odes-why-does-higher-accuracy-and-precision-not-lead-t
Maybe you could also try a higher-order integrator, e.g this ode87 version available for matlab here : https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3616-ode87-integrator.

I'll give ode87 a try.
The given tolerances were 'Reltol',1e-10,'AbsTol',1e-11 and thought that was already very "tight". Please also see my comment to whpowell regarding total number of steps taken.

@KZ-Spectra Regarding the tolerances, I think you didn't read my full answer.  I said "this doesn't seem to be the issue".

Ah, I see that now, thank you. Since it seems that indeed this problem is ill-posed, which means long time dynamics cannot be simulated with trust, what is considered as long time? Is it anything after the point for which the ode solvers do not agree?

That is a reasonable proxy, but a more precise answer might be $t_{crit}\approx -\frac{1}{\lambda}\ln |\tau|$, where $\lambda$ is the largest Lyaponuv exponent and $\tau$ is the local truncation error incurred at the first time step. This comes from the fact that the relative between two trajectories grows like $\delta(t)\approx e^{\lambda t}$. Here we can see that even cutting the error by large factors results in minuscule gains in the accurate time horizon

@KZ-Spectra You're really getting into some complicated and completely different questions.  I don't think the comments here are the right place to try to ask and answer them.
